# Firebug: Angular stack traces do not show the source of the error(line number, file)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebug, stack-trace

I'm trying to get stack traces in Angular which tell me where I went wrong. Instead, I simply get a list of where the error propagated through Angular. Sometimes the error message helps, but not always, but that's beside the point for me: I want to know the exact line number, as well as the file name, where my code bugged out. For example, here is a typical Firebug message:

Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'TackleController' is not a function, got undefined http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.3/ng/areq?p0=TackleController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined minErr/< @http://
localhost:63342/fishing/bower_components/angular/angular.js:63:12 assertArg@http://
localhost:63342/fishing/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1560:1 assertArgFn@http://
localhost:63342/fishing/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1570:1 $ControllerProvider/this.$get< /<@http://
localhost:63342/fishing/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8347:9 nodeLinkFn/<@http://
localhost:63342/fishing/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7517:34 forEach@http://
localhost:63342/fishing/bower_components/angular/angular.js:330:11 nodeLinkFn@http://
localhost:63342/fishing/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7504:11 compositeLinkFn@http://
localhost:63342/fishing/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7003:13 compositeLinkFn@http://
localhost:63342/fishing/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7006:13 publicLinkFn@http://
localhost:63342/fishing/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6882:30 bootstrapApply/<
@http://
localhost:63342/fishing/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1439:11 $RootScopeProvider/this.$get< /Scope.prototype.$eval@http://
localhost:63342/fishing/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14204:16 $RootScopeProvider/this.$get< /Scope.prototype.$apply@http://
localhost:63342/fishing/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14302:18 bootstrapApply@http://
localhost:63342/fishing/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1437:9 invoke@http://
localhost:63342/fishing/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4129:14 bootstrap/doBootstrap@http://
localhost:63342/fishing/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1435:1 bootstrap@http://
localhost:63342/fishing/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1455:1 angularInit@http://
localhost:63342/fishing/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1349:5 @http://
localhost:63342/fishing/bower_components/angular/angular.js:25746:5 trigger@http://
localhost:63342/fishing/bower_components/angular/angular.js:2720:7 createEventHandler/eventHandler@http://
localhost:63342/fishing/bower_components/angular/angular.js:2990:9

In this case, the problem is that I referenced a controller in my HTML which I hadn't defined; I'm posting this as an example of what I mean, not because I want help with the problem. I'm guessing it's because Firebug automatically truncates the stack trace at 20 errors?? But how could I change that?

P.S.
I'm a noob to Angular. If this answer is duplicated somewhere else, please, please, actually link me to the question, instead of hamhandedly deleting the question.

Comment: can you show us some code what you wrote?As per error it shows `Argument 'TackleController' is not a function, got undefined`

Comment: I didn't define TackleController at all. My point in showing the errors was that they do not indicate at which line I tried to reference an undefined variable. That's what I want to get, the actual line number that an error is at. I don't care about this specific error because I already know why it got thrown.

Comment: still no clue without seen the code I can't answer

Comment: The ironic part is that you're complaining about the lack of shown source code...which is what OP is complaining about as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.onerror` to get the specifics of unhandled exceptions:

```
 window.onerror = function (message, url, lineNo)
  {
  console.log('Error: ' + message + '\n' + 'Line Number: ' + lineNo);

  return true;
  }

console.log(window);
console.log(1=2);
```

**References**

- [Better Error Handling With window.onerror](http://dev.opera.com/articles/better-error-handling-with-window-onerror/)
- [W3C Wiki: window.onerror](http://www.w3.org/wiki/DOM/window.onerror)